# Migrate npm packages between private feeds

Tags: npm, data-migration, azure-artifacts, proget

I need to migrate npm packages from Proget npm private feed to Azure Artifacts.
On ProGet server i have folder with thousands of packages, and nobody knows, which of them private.
packages.json file is missing.
I tried npm init to create packages.json, but it fails on scoped packages.
Any ideas, how to get npm packages from root folder and put all of them to private feed?

Answer (score 0):

Does ProGet have the npm packages at .tar.gz files? Or only as expanded files? If .tar.gz, you could download all of those and then upload them all to Azure Artifacts by writing a script that called `npm publish` on each .tar.gz.

Comment: Part of them expanded, part at .tar.gz files